# How to start a service in background and using subprocess and storing the logs in a file

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

Is it possible to execute a shell command which is an infinite process and side by side viewing its logs without use of screen command. Use of `Subprocess` is recommended.

For example:

```
env = os.environ.copy()
proc = subprocess.Popen(
cmds,
shell=False,
stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
bufsize=0,
stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
env=env)
```

where `cmds` is an infinite running process(a service).

Answer (score 0):

like this:

```
$CommandThatProduceOutputs 1>/path/to/your/log/file  2>&1   &
```

then this process will unver background and all STD and ERR stream will logging into the specified `log` file.

For more detail, please visit my blog [linux-shell-redirect](http://rugal.github.io/linux/2013/07/29/linux-shell-redirect/)

Comment: That means in my case, cmds which is a list, say: cmds ['python', 'somefile.py','1>/path/logfile/, '2>&1', '&'  ]

Comment: what do you want to say?

Comment: I mean, what will be my cmds, i am passing in subroutine (in my case cmds is a list cmds = ["python","p.py", "--debug"])

Comment: I think you can just use a loop to achieve this, `python` is rather easy to cope with it